# SQL Query building , require suggestion

Tags: mysql, sql, resultset

Could you pls help me on the below query,

I have queried a result set by joining two three tables as below,

[image]

My requirement is to get the two entries after july 1st 2017 and two entries before july 1st 2017 for every accounts.

Screenshot attached for example, where green rows should come in the final result.

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ac_no, tran_date < '2017-07-01' order by rand()) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) cte
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Note: this puts transactions on 2017-07-01 in the "after" group.  If you don't want them at all, just filter them out in the subquery.

The equivalent logic in SQL Server is:

```
             row_number() over (partition by ac_no, case when tran_date < '2017-07-01' then 1 else 2 end order by newid()) as seqnum
```

Comment: I added this code ,but getting errors as below,

Comment: First if I am using '<' in the partition by its showing "incorrect syntax near '<' and second when removing this and only using tran_date it is showing multipart identifier could not be bound...

Comment: @SandipDas . . . This should work in MySQL, which is the database tag on your question.

Comment: yes in mysql only, TSQL query I mean to say

Comment: now multipart identifier error fixed, but still cant use '<' inside the partition by clause

Comment: pls suggest , .

Comment: Thank you!!, but when using this query its actually giving result as below, let say if we have entry for 20170720 its giving 1 and for 20170820 its giving 2 ...and when for 20170220 its giving again 1 and 20170320 giving 2 and so on.. and for 20160120 it also gives 1 ..then how to sort out only the cosequetive data > 20170701 ...I only need the two entries after 20170701 ..and two entries before 20170701 ..

Comment: @SandipDas . . . That is not the question you asked here.  You asked for any results.  I would suggest that you ask a new question, provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood it, but I stated that green rows should come.. Eg, 456 account number is having 7 entries.. where 201607 and 201608 is in green i.e. before 20170701 and two row in green after 20170701 i.e. 20170725 and 20170825 but if you notice 20170925 is not in green also similar way 20160625 and 20160725 is not in green.... means " 2 entries <20170701> 2 entries "

Comment: please help me sir